# Build multiple independent maven projects using Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

We have nearly **20+** projects which depends on one `common` project. Whenever I make a change in common code. I need to build all 20 projects using Jenkins jobs.

Now I am looking for a way to reduce these manual efforts and build all these 20+ projects on demand basis.

Is there any way with which we can build a list of multiple independent projects in one shot?

Answer (score 0):

You need

> build all 20 projects after a common project is built using Jenkins
> jobs

When you push new tag (new version) to `common` (has web hook event),

- Action 1: push it (JAR artifact) to your private Maven repository ,
- Action 2: (after Action 1 a time, for example 3 minutes) trigger build event with 20 other projects. Publish 30 artifacts to your private Maven repository.

Comment: I can build and push the jar to artifactory of Common but the later part is not clear, like how can I build more than one project?

Comment: Yes, build more than project, because you have 1 + 20 = 21 projects.